# Nav Styling not working in IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

The styling of the `<nav>` is not working in IE8 on the internal pages. What is weird is that it works ALMOST perfectly on the homepage, with the exception of the fact that it drops to the right instead of down.

Site: searchtransparency(dot)net/trc/

Answer (score 4):

IE8 [does not understand](http://caniuse.com/#search=nav) HTML5 elements. You can use the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/) to make IE8 "see" the elements. Paul Irish also wrote a [blog article](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/) about the html5shiv.

To use it, just add the following to your page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```